# Is it possible to have a cumulative sum across columns and not rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible in SQL to get a cumulative sum column wise?

Example:

```
Code    V1     V2     V3     V4         
1        1      2     2       6
```

I want the output to be:

```
Code1   V1      V2        V3     V4     
1        1        3        5     11
```

`So V1 = V1
V2 = V1 + V2 
V3 = V1 + V2 + V3 
… etc`

And this will go on for a lot of columns V1 to V60 which is why I want a fast method of doing it. But I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Can you add the table structure with some sample data?

Comment: IMHO I wouldn't do this, cause doing things in SQL across columns is always complicated and error-prone. Instead do the aggregation in your software that receives the table. Doesn't matter if C#, JavaScript, whatever, but AFAIK it is much simpler in these domains to do this kind of stuff than in SQL.

Comment: @Data_x99 . . . Given this format, the simplest and best performing method is probably going to be simple addition.  You have an issue with your data model.  You should be storing the values in separate rows rather than columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You triggered my couriosity... Might be interesting for you, that your comment above holds true for a lot of columns, but there is a *break even* when a series of `apply` comes up. In my test this was with about 30 columns (code is in my answer). And yes, I know: This is not a real-world scenario where one would use a different design :-)

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier to type/generate/read:

*credits to uberbloke for the ddl and dml*

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE (
    CODE INTEGER
    , V1 INTEGER
    , V2 INTEGER
    , V3 INTEGER
    , V4 INTEGER
)

INSERT INTO @mockupTable
SELECT 1, 1, 2, 2, 6
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 3, 5, 7, 9;

SELECT t.CODE
      ,t.V1 AS sum1
      ,sum2
      ,sum3
      ,sum4
      --add more
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT t.V1+t.V2) T1(sum2)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum2+t.V3) T2(sum3)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum3+t.V4) T3(sum4)
--add more
```

You can create the 60 lines of code easily within EXCEL or with a simple hand-written script over a running number...

The idea is, to use `CROSS APPLY` and deal with the output similar to a variable.

If you find the time to compare the approaches

```
a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d...
```

and this

```
a, a+b, (sum a+b)+c, (sum a+b+c)+d, ...
```

I would be happy to read your performance results...

### UPDATE: Performance...

I did some performance comparison between a simple sum-up and the approach with `apply`. Not surprisingly, the sum-up is faster with a smaller set of columns, while the approach with `apply` *takes over* at about 30 columns. So - with the given 60 columns - the approach using `apply` should perform slightly better.

The code, if interested:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE dbTest;
GO
USE dbTest;
GO
--a table with 40 columns
CREATE TABLE tblTest(ID INT IDENTITY,v1 INT NOT NULL,v2 INT NOT NULL,v3 INT NOT NULL,v4 INT NOT NULL,v5 INT NOT NULL,v6 INT NOT NULL,v7 INT NOT NULL,v8 INT NOT NULL ,v9 INT NOT NULL,v10 INT NOT NULL  
                                    ,v11 INT NOT NULL,v12 INT NOT NULL,v13 INT NOT NULL,v14 INT NOT NULL,v15 INT NOT NULL,v16 INT NOT NULL,v17 INT NOT NULL,v18 INT NOT NULL ,v19 INT NOT NULL,v20 INT NOT NULL
                                    ,v21 INT NOT NULL,v22 INT NOT NULL,v23 INT NOT NULL,v24 INT NOT NULL,v25 INT NOT NULL,v26 INT NOT NULL,v27 INT NOT NULL,v28 INT NOT NULL ,v29 INT NOT NULL,v30 INT NOT NULL
                                    ,v31 INT NOT NULL,v32 INT NOT NULL,v33 INT NOT NULL,v34 INT NOT NULL,v35 INT NOT NULL,v36 INT NOT NULL,v37 INT NOT NULL,v38 INT NOT NULL ,v39 INT NOT NULL,v40 INT NOT NULL)
GO
--we fill these columns with random values
INSERT INTO tblTest(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11,v12,v13,v14,v15,v16,v17,v18,v19,v20,v21,v22,v23,v24,v25,v26,v27,v28,v29,v30,v31,v32,v33,v34,v35,v36,v37,v38,v39,v40) 
                   VALUES(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT)
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT) 
                         ,CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(1)) AS INT));
GO 100000 --create a lot of rows
```

--Start the first test

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();

SELECT ID 
      ,v1 AS sum1
      ,v1+v2 AS sum2
      ,v1+v2+v3 AS sum3
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4 AS sum4
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5 AS sum5
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6 AS sum6
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7 AS sum7
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8 AS sum8
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9 AS sum9
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10 AS sum10
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11 AS sum11
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12 AS sum12
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13 AS sum13
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14 AS sum14
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15 AS sum15
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16 AS sum16
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17 AS sum17
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18 AS sum18
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19 AS sum19
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20 AS sum20
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21 AS sum21
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22 AS sum22
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23 AS sum23
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24 AS sum24
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25 AS sum25
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26 AS sum26
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27 AS sum27
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28 AS sum28
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29 AS sum29
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30 AS sum30
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31 AS sum31
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31+v32 AS sum32
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31+v32+v33 AS sum33
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31+v32+v33+v34 AS sum34
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31+v32+v33+v34+v35 AS sum35
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31+v32+v33+v34+v35+v36 AS sum36
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31+v32+v33+v34+v35+v36+v37 AS sum37
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31+v32+v33+v34+v35+v36+v37+v38 AS sum38
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31+v32+v33+v34+v35+v36+v37+v38+v39 AS sum39
      ,v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7+v8+v9+v10+v11+v12+v13+v14+v15+v16+v17+v18+v19+v20+v21+v22+v23+v24+v25+v26+v27+v28+v29+v30+v31+v32+v33+v34+v35+v36+v37+v38+v39+v40 AS sum40
INTO tblResult1
FROM tblTest;

SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()) as simple_sum_up;
GO
```

--Start the second test

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME2=SYSUTCDATETIME();

SELECT ID
      ,v1 AS sum1
      ,sum2
      ,sum3
      ,sum4
      ,sum5
      ,sum6
      ,sum7
      ,sum8
      ,sum9
      ,sum10
      ,sum11
      ,sum12
      ,sum13
      ,sum14
      ,sum15
      ,sum16
      ,sum17
      ,sum18
      ,sum19
      ,sum20
      ,sum21
      ,sum22
      ,sum23
      ,sum24
      ,sum25
      ,sum26
      ,sum27
      ,sum28
      ,sum29
      ,sum30
      ,sum31
      ,sum32
      ,sum33
      ,sum34
      ,sum35
      ,sum36
      ,sum37
      ,sum38
      ,sum39
      ,sum40
INTO tblResult2
FROM tblTest
CROSS APPLY(SELECT v1+v2) T1(sum2)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum2+v3) T2(sum3)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum3+v4) T3(sum4)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum4+v5) T4(sum5)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum5+v6) T5(sum6)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum6+v7) T6(sum7)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum7+v8) T7(sum8)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum8+v9) T8(sum9)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum9+v10) T9(sum10)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum10+v11) T10(sum11)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum11+v12) T11(sum12)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum12+v13) T12(sum13)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum13+v14) T13(sum14)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum14+v15) T14(sum15)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum15+v16) T15(sum16)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum16+v17) T16(sum17)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum17+v18) T17(sum18)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum18+v19) T18(sum19)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum19+v20) T19(sum20)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum20+v21) T20(sum21)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum21+v22) T21(sum22)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum22+v23) T22(sum23)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum23+v24) T23(sum24)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum24+v25) T24(sum25)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum25+v26) T25(sum26)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum26+v27) T26(sum27)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum27+v28) T27(sum28)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum28+v29) T28(sum29)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum29+v30) T29(sum30)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum30+v31) T30(sum31)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum31+v32) T31(sum32)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum32+v33) T32(sum33)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum33+v34) T33(sum34)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum34+v35) T34(sum35)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum35+v36) T35(sum36)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum36+v37) T36(sum37)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum37+v38) T37(sum38)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum38+v39) T38(sum39)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT sum39+v40) T39(sum40);
SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@d,SYSUTCDATETIME()) as using_apply;
GO
```

--Clean-up (carefull with real data!)

```
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE dbTest;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite unusual task for a relation database, but there's `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` operations to help you. They basically [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) columns to rows and back.

What you could do is:

- UNPIVOT the table to get something like

  ```
  Code Col Value
  1    V1  1
  1    V2  2
  1    V3  2
  1    V4  6
  ```
- Perform the required computation
- PIVOT the result to get the rows back to columns

The documentation for PIVOT and UNPIVOT is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017), unfortunately, it's not very exhausting, so you'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy route in SQL here, as others say you can unpivot but that still needs you to type the columns out. This would be best handled on the reporting side rather than in the database but if you have to do it here's a way to dynamically generate the code for the needed columns.
Just adapt the value going in to the variable for the exact number of columns you need then copy out of the ColumnCode column.

```
   DECLARE @ColumnCount int = 60;
    WITH
    L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5) 
    SELECT N.n,
    STUFF(
        (SELECT ' + V' + cast(C.n as varchar(10)) FROM Nums AS C WHERE C.n <= N.n FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,3,'') + ' AS V' + cast(N.n as varchar(10)) AS ColumnCode
    FROM Nums AS N
    WHERE N <= @ColumnCount
```